# How to divide every 10th number by 10 in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list consisting of 1 million numbers e.g:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,200,.......]
```

in which every 10th number is 10 times what it should be.  I would like to correct the list so that every 10th number will be divided by 10.

I have tried `for i%10==0 then i=i/10` but it seems to not work for a list.

Comment: Can you show us the exact code you used and how it isn't working?

Comment: the file was originally a text, i convert it into a list
f = open('burettes(1).txt', "r")
N=[]
for line in f:
    N.append(float(line.strip('\n')))
    for i in N:
        j=i+1
        if j%10==0:
            j=j/10
print (N)

Comment: Hint: Use ` to format inline code. Also makes data arrays and calculus more readable...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a conditional inside a list comprehension, conditioning on the position of the element (via `enumerate`):

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,200]

# Quotient on 9 because lists are 0-indexed
y = [x/10. if i%10==9 else x for i, x in enumerate(X)]
```

```
print(y)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in-place with an assignment to a slice:

```
a = list(range(30))
a[::10] = [n//10 for n in a[::10]]
```

For really large arrays, however, you might be better off with NumPy which will allow:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(30)
a[::10] //= 10
```